# subscribe if condition meet otherwise return/exit rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

How can i check the condition before it subscribe within the operator chain? I have something like this.

```
parentElem:boolean = false; // the parent elem show/hide;


// inside the ngAfterViewInit();
this.myForm.get('grandParent').valueChanges
//.takeWhile(...) no idea if it works with my condition or not.
//.skipWhile(...) no idea if it works with my condition or not.
.map(val => {
      // i want to return from here if some condition is falsy;
      if(!this.parentElem) return; // how can i return/exit from here? 

      // otherwise return that service and subscribe;
      this.$parent.empty();
      return this.dropdownProvider.getParent(val);

}).subscribe(service => service.subscribe(data => {
      data = data.map(d => {
         return { id: d.text, text: d.text
      };
});
    this.initParent(data);
}));
```

This function change the property value.

```
onDropdownChange(event:Event)
{
   this.parentElem = event.value === 'parent';
}
```

html Element

```
<select (change)="onDropdownChange($event)">
 ...
</select>
```

Already tried with `.takeWhile(...)` & `.skipWhile(...)` but i have no idea that whether it works with my condition or not.

Comment: I guess you could use just `...valueChanges.filter(() => this.parentElem)...`?

Comment: Thanks @martin its working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved by doing this.

```
this.myForm.get('grandParent').valueChanges
           .filter(() => this.parentElem && ...more conditions) // only execute further chain if true;
           .map(val => {

                    this.$parent.empty();
                    return this.dropdownProvider.getParent(val);

         }).subscribe(service => service.subscribe(data => {

              data = data.map(d => { return { id: d.text, text: d.text };   });
              this.initParent(data);

        }));
```